# Popup menu next to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am after a little help with some css/ jquery.
I'm trying to create the following but struggling to show the popup menu next to the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC8sR.jpg

I found this to style the arrow: 
http://cssarrowplease.com/

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please share your code and show what you have tried or create a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is without doubt at least 100 plugins that are doing exactly that out there.

Comment: can you maybe post a recommended one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I suggest you to test your code on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

I give you a little tip for you purpose, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zTYu6/).

What happen? When you click circle, fadeIn arrowed menu:

```
$('#expand').on('click', function() {
     $('.arrow_box').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the headstart.

iv modified your fiddle and have it working
http://jsfiddle.net/zTYu6/1/
much appreciated